# NativeScript: how to show the side drawer from the home page?

Tags: angular, navigation, nativescript, navigation-drawer

I'm writing an app with Angular 8 and NativeScript 6.4.1.

I want to implement a Side Drawer that will only show when the hamburger button is pushed on the home page. I don't want it to show any other time.

I have read this document: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/ng-SideDrawer/getting-started#initialization

I tried to implement this side drawer and it keep giving me this error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDrawer' of undefined"
```

Here is my playground:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ujiNiC&v=2

code snippet:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(SideDrawerComponent, { static: false }) public drawerComponent: SideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    public openSideDrawer() {
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not access a component that's not within its own template. Create a service with a rxjs boolean Subject, subscribe to the subject in side drawer component, upon value change open / close drawer. Use the same subject in home component to trigger the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

You're not setting `RadSideDrawer` in the right way. You need to set the drawer at the root view, and mark drawer content with the `tkDrawerContent` selector, and the angular router with the `tkMainContent` selector.

In details, you need to:

Firstly, set `RadSideDrawer` at the topmost component of your app, i.e. on the app.component.html, so that there is the side drawer content, marked with the `tkDrawerContent` selector, and the rest of the content (the content of your app), marked with the `tkMainContent` selector. If you're using Angular router then add it to `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`, as appears below:

**app.component.html:**

```
<RadSideDrawer>
    <GridLayout tkDrawerContent rows="auto, *">
        <!-- content of the drawer -->
    </GridLayout>

    <page-router-outlet tkMainContent></page-router-outlet>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

You can render any custom component that you have instead/inside the *tkDrawerContent* marked GridLayout above.

Secondly, make sure to import `NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule` into the module that loads the component that has `<RadSideDrawer>` inside it. In my example, it is the **app.module**.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
```

Thirdly, to open/close the side drawer, you need to access it through the app RootView. Inside your component add these:

**home.componenet.ts:**

Import:

```
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer';
```

And inside your class:

```
public openSideDrawer() {
    const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
    sideDrawer.showDrawer();
}
```

If your app becomes very complex with multiple pages and routes, then you can add the code to open/close the drawer in a ui service injected at root, or in a shared custom actionBar component.

A fix to your example is [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ujiNiC&v=3).

Happy nativescripting!